# Why am I getting warning when I try to create new JavaFx project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

[image: JavaFx-ErrorMessage]I am using jdk 1.8 (it is Java 8 as far as I know)for my JavaFx project. When I try to create new project the following warning shows up :

" The required java version 11 is not supported by the project SDK "1.8"
The maximum supported Java version is 8 "

Which I don't get as I am not using java 11. I like java 8 as it has built in javafx. What should I do now to solve this problem?

Comment: There are other distributions which include JavaFX beyond version 8. Two of them are _Bellsoft Liberica_ and _Azul Zulu_. They are builds of OpenJDK/OpenJFX and so should be mostly similar to, if not exactly the same as, a JDK/JRE downloaded from Oracle. If you download one of these distributions make sure you choose the package the contains JavaFX.

Comment: "What should I do now to solve this problem?" -> You should use a recent version of JavaFX, e.g. 16. As much as you like Java 8 because it has built-in JavaFX, it is now obsolete and, so, it is no longer recommended to use it for JavaFX development.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Java 11 to use JavaFX in IntelliJ Idea. Take a look at official documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html#create-project

> Java 11 or later is required to create JavaFX applications.

Comment: Ohh, I see , Thanks a lot, I should switch to the previous version of intellij

Comment: This is not accurate as IntelliJ IDEA does still support JavaFX applications using JDK 8. It appears they have removed support for pre-11 versions of JDK from the project creation wizard, but JavaFX projects can still be created manually just fine.